# Не корректный Json на Массив

Tags: php, json, qiwi

Получаю ответ от сервера

```
'{bill:{siteId:2304,billId:151989213804fhr7i272a2,amount:{value:1,currency:RUB},status:{value:PAID,datetime:2018-03-01T11:16:12},customer:{},customFields:{},creationDateTime:2018-03-01T11:15:39,expirationDateTime:2018-04-01T11:15:39+03:00},version:1}
```

Таком виде как его мне обработать в массив ?

Пробовал `json_decode($response, true);` получаю **пустой массив** или же **1**

Comment: где все кавычки-то?

Comment: Вот именно их не было решил проблему) было дело в тестовом запросе через curl. Сервер отправляет с кавычками.